# Pandas: Wideset dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to wideset the data frame every time there's a duplicate matching `time` + `image` column.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

This dataframe:

```
    Time                Image   YorN    Result      Name    Value
    2020-11-21 13:40:56 W402    Y       ACCEPTED    David   2.11
    2020-11-21 13:41:03 W403    Y       ACCEPTED    David   1.04
    2020-11-21 13:45:16 W404    Y       REJECTED    David   18.31
    2020-11-21 13:45:16 W404    N       ACCEPTED    Super   80.69
    2020-11-21 14:01:01 W405    Y       ACCEPTED    Harry   1.41
    2020-11-21 14:01:07 NaN     nan     NaN         NaN     NaN
```

Row 3 and 4 both have the same `time` and `image` id and hence this row would be widesetted.

Desired dataframe:

```
    Time                Image   YorN    Result      Name    Value   Result2  Name2  Value2
    2020-11-21 13:40:56 W402    Y       ACCEPTED    David   2.11    NaN      NaN    NaN
    2020-11-21 13:41:03 W403    Y       ACCEPTED    David   1.04    NaN      NaN    NaN
    2020-11-21 13:45:16 W404    Y       REJECTED    David   18.31   ACCEPTED Super  80.69
    2020-11-21 14:01:01 W405    Y       ACCEPTED    Harry   1.41    NaN      NaN    NaN
    2020-11-21 14:01:07 NaN     nan     NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter of repeated columns, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), flatten `MultiIndex` and last convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df = (df.set_index(['Time','Image', df.groupby(['Time','Image']).cumcount().add(1)])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
                  Time Image YorN1   Result1  Name1  Value1 YorN2   Result2  \
0  2020-11-21 13:40:56  W402     Y  ACCEPTED  David    2.11   NaN       NaN   
1  2020-11-21 13:41:03  W403     Y  ACCEPTED  David    1.04   NaN       NaN   
2  2020-11-21 13:45:16  W404     Y  REJECTED  David   18.31     N  ACCEPTED   
3  2020-11-21 14:01:01  W405     Y  ACCEPTED  Harry    1.41   NaN       NaN   
4  2020-11-21 14:01:07   NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN   

   Name2  Value2  
0    NaN     NaN  
1    NaN     NaN  
2  Super   80.69  
3    NaN     NaN  
4    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: The solution works almost perfectly, however, also creates YorN3 ,Result3, Name3 , Value3 , --4,5,6, and so on columns. All with nan values.

Comment: @HarriS - Yes, it is expected. Because it means at least one row with non missing data. It is same like this output - for `2020-11-21 13:45:16  W404` are only data in row for new columns with suffix `2`, all another rows are filled by NaNs. If large data it seems there are missing values onlym beacuse 1 rows should be easy overlooked.